# LANG variable wrong in iTerm2, where's the bug?

Tags: internationalization, iterm, language

Today I noticed that when opening TortoiseHG the app was in Dutch (partially, not fully translated it seems). Looking around in my environment I found out that `LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8`.

It is indeed true that my locale is set to NL (i.e. number formats and all) but my language in OS X is set to English and I would expect my apps to be in English aswell. A locale is quite different from a language.

So my question is now, where do I report this bug to? Is it an iTerm2 issue or do I need to file a bug report somewhere else?

**My goal is to have my number format according to Dutch standards (i.e. 123.456 = 123 thousand and 456 and my language still at English. OS X gets this, iTerm2 (or at least, TortoiseHG started from iTerm2) does not.**

[image: System Preferences - Language]
[image: System Preferences - Region]

```
# locale
LANG="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Versions:

- OS X: 10.8.2
- iTerm 2: 1.0.0.20120724
- TurtoiseHG: 2.4

Comment: More likely you are exporting this value somewhere in your shell login scripts. Did you have a look at .profile etc?

Comment: No, it's being done by iTerm2 (can be disabled in settings -> profiles -> terminal -> set locale variables automatically)

Answer (score 10):

The following will do the trick:
Navigate to the
iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal 
and unset the "Set local variables automatically" in Environment section.

Answer (score 7):

In both iTerm and Terminal the LC_ variables depend on the region selected in System Preferences (`defaults read -g AppleLocale`) by default. Both have preferences for using the C locale though:

- iTerm: Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Set locale variables automatically
- Terminal: Preferences > Settings > Advanced > Set locale environment variables on startup

You could also add `export LANG=C` to your shell profile.

```
$ defaults read -g AppleLocale
ja_JP
$ locale
LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ dddd
-bash: dddd: コマンドが見つかりません
$ export LANG=C
$ dddd
-bash: dddd: command not found
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. That seems wrong though, a locale is not a language. Just because I want my numbers to be formatted like this: `123.456,789` for 123 thousand... doesn't mean that I want my programs to be in Dutch. So this would appear to be a bug somewhere.

Comment: @WoLpH a locale contains a language.

Comment: @Gerry: Please tell me how I can set my number format to the Dutch standard when keeping my language English (as I have it configured in OS X, but iTerm2 doesn't seem to get that).

Comment: @WoLpH, the answer is above, export the Dutch locale for formatting, and en_US for LANG instead of relying on iTerm2 to export these for you.

Comment: @Gerry: I guess that works, I'll report it as a bug in iTerm2 in that case since it's not using the settings as defined in OSX.

Comment: @WoLpH, I don't see how this is a bug. You are telling it to export locale variables automatically based on your selected locale in Mac OS X. If you don't want to rely on this you can set these environment variables manually.

Comment: @Gerry: my Region (i.e. number format) is set to Dutch, my language (which is the locale according to you) is set to English. It seems that it is using the wrong variable in that case, is it not?

Comment: @Gerry: I've added screenshots to clarify :)