Can't clear check_language_envvar("LC_ALL") warning when running R scripts
Whenever I run an R script I get the following warning that I can't clear:
Warning messages:
1: In check_language_envvar("LC_ALL") :
  Changing language has no effect when envvar LC_ALL='C'
2: In check_language_envvar("LC_ALL") :
  Changing language has no effect when envvar LC_ALL='C'

When I type locale into iTerm, I get the following output:
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL="C"

I have absolutely no idea how to solve the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

What problem were you trying to fix that you changed the LC settings?

I haven’t changed any settings. I only get those warnings when I run my R scripts. I started learning R the other day and I’ve been getting these warnings since I ran my first R script. But I don’t get the warnings when I run any other scripts, like JS.

Do you have "Set locale variables automatically" turned on in the terminal emulator?  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/83428/89967 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/451014/89967
